# vi / vim - extra indents when pasting text?

Tags: vim, vi, editors, paste

I can copy characters in other apps such as browsers with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

I can then press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode in vim and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste the text in.

The problem is that each line gets indented a bit more so I end up with:

[image]

but what I want (and end up manually editing to achieve) is:[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `:set paste` prevents vim from re-tabbing my code and fixes the problem.
Also, `:set nopaste` turns it off

I also put `set pastetoggle=<F2>`in my .vimrc so I can toggle it with the <kbd>F2</kbd> key.